# How can i create a /tmp partition

Tags: rhel, tmp

i'm trying to intall RHEL Linux Server 7.4 using VMware through a **dvd.iso**
i want to create a partition for the **/tmp** during the installation, knowing that the graphical interface that permit customizing partitions lasts in few seconds !

Comment: You can create it later, edit `/etc/fstab` and reboot. But do not allocate all the diskspace

Answer (score 0):

The [RHEL7 installation guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/) has a [section](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-disk-partitioning-setup-x86#sect-custom-partitioning-x86) specifically describing how to create a custom partition scheme. Create your /tmp along side other partitions there.

Also, please use the RHEL 7.6 installation media instead of 7.4. It has all the latest fixes in it, and will speed up how long it takes to get all your software updates after you install, since there will be fewer.